# How do I fix odd waveform/playback import issues in Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live, waveform, importing

I recorded a few tracks in Ableton Live for a client, then exported them so he could have a friend pitch correct them using Melodyne.  After getting the tracks back and importing them into Ableton Live, the waveforms look very different compared to other tracks:

[image: weird waveforms on imported tracks]

The top two tracks are imported and the bottom two are ones I recorded myself.

In addition, if I try to play one of these tracks, I hear a very loud sound and then all sound cuts out.  If I reload the project and mute the problem tracks the mix plays normally.

The files I imported sound fine when I play them back in macOS Finder.  I tried using Ableton Live's Utility plugin to solve the problem by clicking on "DC" in case there was a DC offset issue but this did not appear to fix anything.

I also tried importing the tracks into a new Live project.  They played back without cutting out all sound but adjusting the clip or track volume seemed to have no effect.  It sounds like someone turned the volume all the way up on a cheap sound system when it plays back.

What exactly is going on here?  How can I fix this issue?

Comment: is there a way of recreating or reimporting the tracks so that the waveforms are re-generated?

Comment: @Mark hey I tried deleting the auto-generated waveform files but Live just recreates them as is 

Comment: Is it possible that they are coming back from Melodyne in a different format? i.e. different endianness, different bit resolution etc?

Comment: Actually, why don't you post both tracks. One before going through melodyne and one after coming back from Melodyne. I think there is a corruption issue possibly.

Comment: @mark good call with the bit resolution.  The tracks I got back are 32 bits but the originals (and the project I assume) are 16 bits.  I'll try converting them and let you know what happens.

Comment: ah yes - you probably have 32-bit float representation in there, rather than integer samples. That's likely going to stuff something up. I have punched in an answer in the hope that we've nailed it.

Comment: I notice the irony in your username too.... ;-)

Comment: @mark it looks like my projects had a bit depth of 24 and the files I got back had a bit depth of 32, so my project couldn't handle them.  I used FFMPEG to convert them to a bit depth of 16 (which I was using in my project) and it works fine now.  Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: were they 32 bit float or 32 bit int - just out of interest?

Comment: @Mark I didn't know there was a difference!  My guess is whichever one is more standard.  The file I got was exported from a DAW and after I converted just the bit depth with FFMPEG I could import it into a DAW okay so nothing too crazy was going on most likely.

Comment: yeah some DAW's will accept and produce floating point sample values - most of the processing internally will be floating point so it makes sense to store the samples as floating point as there is less conversion to do when you open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have an issue with the sample format in the incoming file. 
WAV files are able to contain a number of different sample values, including different bit-resolutions of integer and double (32-bit float) or quad-precision (64-bit) float representations of samples.

Ensure that the sample format that you are using is compatible with the DAW, if not - check and convert the file to a compatible format.

Comment: In my particular case it was bit depth/bit resolution, but all of these things are good to look out for.